# Why didn't Tony Stark initiate the House Party Protocol earlier?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-3

At the end of *Iron Man 3*, Tony tells Jarvis to initiate the House Party Protocol, which:

> summons all of the Iron Man suits sitting in the vault beneath the wreckage of his house to fly in and fight as autonomous units.

However, prior to that he'd been working on restoring the Mark 42 unit he had been wearing, but which had been damaged, even though it isn't fully combat ready.

Why did he not initiate the House Party Protocol earlier?

Comment: I think that's only because the movie would have ended before...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They key part is

> wreckage of his house.

All the suits were in the vault, which was underneath his house.  After Mandarin's attack, the vault was buried in rubble.  We didn't see it, but after the attack, the wreckage from the attack was being cleaned up.  At the end of the film, that had progressed far enough that the vault's doors were accessible again (we get a glimpse of this once Tony authorizes House Party, as it shows the workers clearing rubble as the vault doors open).  And so it was House Party time.

Comment: That definitely makes sense.  Was there any indication during the movie that Tony received word that work on clearing the rubble had been completed enough to start the House Party?  I don't recall him asking if House Party was possible yet, but I may have missed it.

Comment: J.A.R.V.I.S. lets him know that the cranes had arrived to clear the "cellar doors" when he is on the Mandarin's boat with Rhodey.

Comment: @Beofett Yes, JARVIS notifies Tony that the vault has been cleared enough to initiate House Party.

Comment: It seems odd that a little bit of wreckage would have been sufficient to keep the armors from exiting their vault. I'd have thought they could either open the door and move the rubble or excavate an alternate exit.

Comment: @Xantec It wasn't a 'little bit' though, it was at the bottom of his house, so whatever parts of his house didn't fall into the ocean were on top of it.

Comment: Eh, compared to seeing what the suits are capable of through the previous three movies, it would seem to be a trivial matter for all of them to blast their way out had Tony wanted them earlier.

Comment: @Xantec They'd be blasting through the workers as well as the wreckage

Comment: It's ok.  The workers are all wearing red shirts.

Comment: In Avengers, Tony & JARVIS seemed to imply that the Mk 7 was being manufactured/fabricated while Tony was gone. Perhaps the House Party Protocol was still undergoing some automated manufacturing/assembling and wasn't fully ready until the end of the film.

Answer (score 6):

Until Tony determined the scope of the Extremis project, specifically the number of people involved, he had to conserve his resources. With his house destroyed, Killian probably assumed Tony to be mostly out of the picture. A nuisance to be sure, but not much of a threat.

If Tony had called for the other suits as soon as he crashed in Kentucky, or when he assaulted the Mandarin's house, then he'd have remained a target of Killian and his troops, which would have made his investigations more difficult and would have resulted in a significant amount of collateral damage. Not to mention that that may have pushed Killian to forcibly create more body-bombs in an attempt to distract Tony.

Instead, Tony waited until Killian baited him, and when he could be reasonably sure that all or most of the Extremis subjects would be present. This enabled Tony to remove as many of the targets as possible at one time, while limiting collateral damage and civilian casualties.

---

Alternatively, JARVIS may not have been capable of controlling all the armors until that point in the movie. The destruction of Tony's house seemed to have had a severe deleterious effect on JARVIS' capabilities, requiring JARVIS to go offline for a large part of the movie. Even once JARVIS was back online to where he speak through the MK 42 armor, he still had issues with some of his systems (such as occasionally substituting an incorrect word at the end of sentences).

As such, to acquire enough processing power to be able to simultaneously coordinate all of the other 40 suits of armor could have takes JARVIS significant time, in activating and/or "borrowing" auxiliary systems and in restoring backup programs and data.

Comment: He was happy for the world to consider him dead while he investigated what was going on. For a good part of the movie he was intentionally keeping a low profile. Having 30-odd Iron Man suits fly out of his wrecked home would have blown that somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle hint at this on the movie. As others have stated, the wreckage was too much and it did not allow the top of the vault to open. Once it was clear enough, JARVIS tells Tony something about the wreckage being cleared enough and that the wine cellar was intact (I'm paraphrasing here, but that's the gist of it), and THAT's when Tony knows (by the coded message from JARVIS) that the suites were fine and that he could initiate the House Party Protocol.

Answer (score -3):

He really should have initiated it during the attack on his house. That seems to be the intention of the protocol after all, to defend his home in a dire situation (given its name). Only reason I can think of for him not to have used it then is if he feared the iron man suits may have attacked the news choppers in the area as well. He did have some trouble specifying targets when he finally did initiate the protocol.

Comment: This is pretty speculative stuff. I don't disagree with your logic but there's no (in-universe) evidence that this was a consideration for him.

Comment: The question being posed is: why didn't he initiate the protocol?